# Editar resposta para adição de código

Tags: debate, edição

Hoje me deparei com [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97224/20615). Ela responde completamente o que o AP solicitou, e explica a forma de fazer com suas referências e com um exemplo funcional.

Minha dúvida é: **Posso editar a resposta do autor adicionando o exemplo que ele mesmo postou?**

Ou a melhor opção é pedir (por comentário) para o autor adicionar o exemplo à resposta?

Pergunto isso pois, apesar de confiável, o [link do exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/hyg8pnrs/) pode não existir "amanhã".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em termos das "regras" do site, eu diria que **sim**, já que você não está alterando o sentido da resposta, nem alterando o código.

Porém o autor pode não gostar. Eu faço isso quando percebo que a pessoa não sabe bem como usar o site, ou quando abandonam uma resposta. No caso de respostas recentes como essa, vale a pena deixar um comentário orientando o próprio autor a fazer isso.

Answer (score 8):

Eu diria que **não**. Poste sua própria resposta, ou se desejar sinalize ao autor da resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Eu diria que sim, já fiz isso e já fizeram isso com respostas minhas. Em geral, pela minha experiência, funciona bem desde que você esteja seguro do que está fazendo. No caso de o autor original não concordar com a alteração, ele sempre pode facilmente retornar à resposta anterior. Minha única ressalva é não começar uma guerra de edits: faça a edição bem feita e faça apenas uma vez